# Finding a difference equation with solution $x_{n}=\alpha n^{2} 3^{-n},n\in\mathbb{N},\alpha\in\Bbb R$

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

How does one find a difference equation which have $x_{n}=\alpha n^{2} 3^{-n},n\in\mathbb{N},\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ as  a solution?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* More generally, for $x_{n}=n^k b^n$, use the characteristic polynomial $(x-b)^{k+1}$.